# Prolog query question

Tags: prolog, water-jug-problem

I am new to prolog, and I have to write a program about the water 
jugs. My problem is regarding the initial state of jugs and the query 
formation. The query will be of the form:

```
?- myPredicate(args), filled(j1,1)
```

Meaning j1 filled with 1 gallon of water. j1 represents one of the jugs; the other is j2. Initally, I have

```
filled(j1,0) 
filled(j2,5) 
capacity(j1,2) 
capacity(j2,5)
```

I would really be grateful if you provide me with information regarding the following:

**Question A:** Do I have to declare initial state of the j1 inside my program? `filled(j1,0)`

**Question B:** I need to make my program find a solution for 
filled(j1,1). For that I have some ideas, but what I am not sure 
about, is how to update filled(J,Volume) from query and 
`myPredicate`.

I am very confused since I have the initial state `filled(j1,0)` and now 
I have to create a `filled(j1,1)` in `myPredicate`. So I should have some form of `filled(J,Volume)` in `myPredicate`, so the query returns true instead of false.

How do I incorporate `filled(J,Voume)` inside `myPredicate` so when the above query is run, I can show correct answer?

Comment: *"...and I **have** to write a program..."* - Is this homework?

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly is the problem. Can you give me a full description of the problem as received from university I guess?
Not knowing what is the exact problem here, I cannot give you an answer, but.. here I found a very similar problem to yours with answer already given http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~ki/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog7.pdf, slide 17th onwards

Answer (score -2):

Example program with a passed-in parameter, an initial fact and an iterative task to perform.  Iteration is by means of recursion. Before each reentry the value related to certain a parameter can be effectively updated for the next pass.

```
my_loop(N) :- N > 10.

my_loop(N) :- N =< 10,
    write(N), nl,
    Nextin is N + 1,
    my_loop(Nextin).

:- my_loop(1).
```

A:
The given information (facts) are needed by
  the program.  They can be made available from keyboard input,  as initial
  arguments to some predicate, or as facts in the database as you
  suggested. Also, only suggested for special situations, the facts
  can be hard-coded into some predicate or rule.

Below and above are example of passing the initial information in as parameters: `:- my_predicate(args...)`.

If there are a lot of facts, the database is best.  A few facts that
  need to change every time is best gotten from the keyboard. Otherwise,
  it probably doesn't matter.

```
:- my_predicate([fill(j1,0),fill(j2,5)], Answer),
    write(Answer),
    nl.
```

B:

See the *my*_ *loop* example:

In my_loop, the task of counting [1..10] is solved iteratively.
  The givens: 1 is passed in as a parameter, mainly because the
  program does the same thing over-and-over:
  1. take a number (N); quit if it is too big. Otherwise...
  2. print it.
  3. calculate the next number (N+1)
  4. repeat

10 is hard-coded. It could have been a fact: `stop_after(10)`.

Now the data to be manipulated, the variable *N* in my_loop, and
  *{ j1,j2 }* in myPredicate doesn't actually need to be re-assigned over-and-over again:  See my_loop.  Just re-enter
  the computation when it's time to do the same
  thing again, but with different parameters:

```
cap(j1,2).
cap(j2,5).

my_predicate(Status, Answer) :-
    got_juice(Status,0),
    Answer=Status.

%%% Instead of changing values, rerun comp. with new values
%%% based on a computation made from the old ones.
my_predicate([filled(j1,J1), filled(j2,J2)], Answer) :-
    Used is J1 + J2,
    got_juice(Used, J), J \= 0,
    cap(j1,C1), cap(C2),
    %% Use cap and filled to add more to filled..
    NextJ1 is J1 + ...,
    NextJ2 is J2 + ...,
    my_predicate(filled(j1,NextJ1), filled(..., Answer).
```

NOTE:
The predicate above is just to demonstrate iteration in Prolog, using the parameters of "myProgaram". For an actual implementation see the program suggested in the comment from matcheek.